# SQL Server SMO programming, where to set the CommandTimeout property?

Tags: c#, sql-server, powershell, smo

I'm working on a PowerShell script with SMO to do some SQL Server programming. The simplified version of my script is listed below.

```
# Load SMO assembly, and if we're running SQL Server 2008 DLLs load the SMOExtended and SQLWMIManagement libraries
$v = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( "Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO");

if ((($v.FullName.Split(','))[1].Split('='))[1].Split('.')[0] -ne '9') {
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMOExtended") | out-null;
}
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoEnum') | out-null;
$server = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server") ".\sql2014";
$server.Databases["master"].ExecuteWithResults("select * from sys.database_files");
```

My script now always times out and I googled around against the internet and found that I should set [`CommandTimeout` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx) somewhere in my code.

However, the property `CommandTimeout` is for `SqlCommand`. The way I use SMO to execute query doesn't have a `SqlCommand` object. As you can see I can execute directly on `$server.Databases["master"]`.

Can anyone help to point out where I should set the `CommandTimeout` property?

Comment: A couple of style comments - try `import-module SQLPS -DisableNameChecking` instead of all that reflection LoadWithPartialName stuff. Also, if you're going to be ultimately selecting data files, actually use the SMO model: databases have FileGroups which in turn have Files. Databases also have LogFiles. But ultimately, you want to use the object representation of these things rather than trying to parse the output of your ad hoc query.

Answer (score 2):

`$server.ConnectionContext.StatementTimeout` should get the job done for you. As per [TechNet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.serverconnection.statementtimeout(v=sql.120).aspx) this:

> Gets or sets the number of seconds a statement is given to run before failing with a time-out error.

Comment: I tested this using a `WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'` setting `$server.ConnectionContext.StatementTimeout` equal to 1 caused it to fail, but setting it to 6 allowed it to succeed; so the value is in seconds.